# complex machine learning application

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

2 questions concerning machine learning algorithms like linear / logistic regression, ANN, SVM:

1. The models in these algorithms are dealing with data sets where each example has a no. of features and one output possible value (ex : getting price of house with features f) but what if the features are enough to produce more than one piece of information about the item of interest which means more than one output?! consider this as an example: a data set about cars where each example (car) has the following features (initial velocity, acceleration, and time), in real world these features are enough to know two variables: velocity via `v = v_i + at` and distance via `s = (v_i * t ) + (0.5 * a *t^2 )` so I want example `X` with features `(x1 , x2 , ... , xn)`  to have output `y1` and `y2` in the same step so that after training the model, if a new car example is given with initial velocity and acc. and time, the model will be able to predict the velocity and distance at the same time, is this possible?
2. in the houses' price prediction example where example `X`  given with features `(x1, x2, x3)` the model predicts the price, can the process be reversed by any means? meaning if I give the model example `X` with features `x1`, `x2` with price `y` can it predict the feature `x3`?

Comment: Q1 isn't clear. Q2 - yes, although you need to code a bit for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depends on the model. A linear model such as linear regression cannot reliably learn the distance formula since it's a cubic function of the given variables. You'd need to add v×t and a×t² as a feature to get a good prediction of the distance. A non-linear model such as a cubic-kernel SVM regression or a multi-layer ANN should be able to learn this from the given features, though, given enough data.

   More generally, predicting multiple values with a single model sometimes works and sometimes doesn't -- when in doubt, just fit several models.
2. You can try. Whether it'll work depends on the relation between the variables and the model.